# creating table for dictionary program

Tags: sql, database

Need help with compiling a database table for a dictionary.
As children, when someone learned a new language, they created their own paper dictionary,
which was divided into 3 columns.

- new word
- transcription of the word
- word translation

Now I'm thinking how I will store it in a table.
My idea is that a user can have several of these dictionaries and each of these dictionaries can have an unlimited number of words. And the question is, what could it look like? I know it's probably not optimal to store this, but still.

```
create table Dictionary(
  id,
  userId,
  Pseudonym(name),
  OriginalWord(?),
  OriginalTransciptionedWord(?),
  TranslatedWord(?)
)
```

Does it look correct? Could you give me some pieces of advice if there is any :)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you might learn more than a single language, there's yet another table to be included into data model.

You didn't say which database you use. This is Oracle syntax, but never mind that as the principle is just the same.

`users` table lets your database handle dictionaries not only for you, but also your friends.

```
SQL>     create table users
  2        (user_id       number constraint pk_users primary key,
  3         username      varchar2(30) not null
  4        );

Table created.
```

Languages (such as German, Italian, Croatian, etc.):

```
SQL>     create table languages
  2        (language_id   number constraint pk_lang primary key,
  3         language_name varchar2(30) not null
  4        );

Table created.
```

The dictionary itself: it contains foreign key columns to both `users` and `languages`, as well as *dictionary* stuff itself (original and translated words):

```
SQL>     create table dictionary
  2        (dict_id       number constraint pk_dict primary key,
  3         user_id       number constraint fk_dict_user references users (user_id),
  4         language_id   number constraint fk_dict_lang references languages (language_id),
  5         --
  6         original_word                 varchar2(30) not null,
  7         original_trasncriptioned_word varchar2(30) not null,
  8         translated_word               varchar2(30) not null
  9        );

Table created.

SQL>
```

So, if you wanted to display someone's dictionary contents for a certain language (both would be passed as parameters), you'd

```
select u.username, l.language_name, d.original_word, d.translated_word
from dictionary d join users u on u.user_id = d.user_id
                  join languages l on l.language_id = d.language_id
where d.user_id = :par_user_id
  and d.language_id = :par_language_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is straightforward and correct. Another thing you might need to consider is database space and how much storage you have available as well as how many users you would have.

You could create a 'Dictionary' table and a 'Users' table, you could then join the dictionary table and the users based on the word.

```
create table Dictionary(
  id,
  OriginalWord,
  OriginalTransciptionedWord,
  TranslatedWord
)

create table Users(
  id,
  userId,
  Pseudonym(name),
  wordId
)
```

Something like:

```
SELECT Dictionary.OriginalWord, Dictionary.OriginalTransciptionedWord, Dictionary.TranslatedWord FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN Dictionary ON Dictionary.wordId = Users.id
WHERE Users.userId = @currentUserId
```

It would lead to a slightly more complex query, however, it would be more space efficient. When adding a new word, you could query to check if it already exists and add that wordId into the Users table. `